# Wygwam 3.3.1 Disappears from Channel Entry

Tags: ee2, wygwam

I've updated to EE 2.8.1 as well as updating Wygwam to 3.3.1 (and a ton of other add-ons).

Since the updates, the Wygwam field will flash and then disappear on any Channel Entry page. This has been the case in Safari, Firefox, Chrome

- I've cleared caches (EE and browser), refreshed, restarted to no avail.
- I've uninstalled Channel Images to no avail.
- I've created a "Naked" Wygwam config with no style set, etc. to no avail.
- I've created a test channel and field set with only an instance of Wygwam to no avail.
- I've manually refreshed the ckeditor.js to no avail.
- I've googled until my fingers bled. To no avail.

I've attached a screenshot from the Inspector which shows an error which is above head.

[image: Inspector Screenshot]

I'm stumped. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried completely re-uploading Wygwam?

Comment: Yeah. Completely re-downloaded and re-installed a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was with a Wygwam configuration. In addition to upgrading Wygwam, I upgraded to Channel Images 5.4.17a. Previously, to use CI in Wygwam, one had to add an Advanced Setting to the Wygwam config (extraPlugins -> "channel images"). Simply removing this setting did the trick.

The new version of CI automatically integrates with Wygwam and does not require that config step (or the addition of anything to the Wygwam theme folder).

Hope this helps somebody down the road.